# Expressing Limit as Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Ive got another question:

Express the limit $lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\pi}{n}sin(\frac{\pi k}{n})$ as a Riemann Integral

I have the knowledge of Riemann Integrals but cant apply it to this question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the definition of a Riemann integral?

Comment: Well a Riemann Integral can be defined as: $\int_a^bf(x)dx=lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_i)\delta{x}$

Comment: and isn't what you have?  $[x_i,x_{i+1}] = [\frac {\pi i}{n}, \frac {\pi (i+1)}{n}], \delta x = \frac {\pi}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{\pi}{n} \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n} \right) \approx \int^1_0 \pi \sin \pi x\ dx. 
\end{align}